# Finding next sibling with a specific child JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I've a UL in this format

```
<UL>
<LI>ABC</LI>
<LI>DEF</LI>
<LI>GHI</LI>
<LI>JKL</LI>
<LI><a class='header'>MNO</a></LI>
<LI>PQR</LI>
<LI>DEF</LI>
<LI>GHI</LI>
<LI>JKL</LI>
<LI><a class='header'>AHP</a></LI>
<LI>GHI</LI>
<LI>JKL</LI>
</UL>
```

I've a variable which holds the second **li** instance.

```
var l=$('ul li:eq(1)');
```

But I need to find the index of the next li with "anchor child" with a class "header". May I know the best way to find that index.

Comment: It will be great to mention why the downvote..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) to retrieve following siblings, filtered using the [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector, then [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) if you only want the first match.

```
l.nextAll(':has(.header)').first();
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m9pznf2e/2/)

Of course you can be more specific in your filter if you need – `li:has(a.header)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of `nextAll` to get the siblings and `filter` to find those containing the required `a`. Try this:

```
var $li = $('ul li:eq(1)');
$li.nextAll('li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('.header').length > 0; 
}).first().addClass('foo');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu08h52m/)